# VBA Like Operator

Tags: vba, outlook, pattern-matching, sql-like

I want to monitor our public e-mail folder for specific new mails to arrive and then use MsgBox to create a pop-up Window. Everything is set up and works prett well apart from the matching part using the `Like` Operator.

I want to match the following string in the subject of the E-Mail:

```
*XXX*YYY*
```

which I manage to do by using:

```
Like "*XXX*YYY*"
```

What I am struggeling with is when someone replies to that E-Mail and the subject changes to:

```
Re:*XXX*YYY* or Aw:*XXX*YYY*
```

If that is the case, I do not want to create a pop-up message since it is an answer to the original E-Mail.

I tried stuff like:

```
If subject Like "*[!aw:]*" & "*[!re:]*" Then
   If subject Like "*XXX*YYY*" Then
```

in various combinations but I do not seem to get it working properly.

Can anyone assist?

Comment: Would you be interested in a solution that utilizes the RegExp library? Regular expressions are extremely powerful and allow you much more control over what you match and what you don't.  They are more complex to understand, but the power you gain is worth the investment of time to learn in my opinion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look for the exceptions, then compare with the wildcard:

```
Select Case UCase$(Left$(subject, 3))

    Case "RE:", "AW:":
        '// is reply
    Case Else
        If subject Like "*XXX*YYY*" Then
            MsgBox "Hello"
        End If

End Select
```

Answer (score 1):

Hmm.. you can use

```
Dim s As String
s = "*XXX*YYYY*"
If (InStr(1, s, "Re:") = 0) And (InStr(1, s, "Aw:") = 0) Then
   If (s Like "*XXX*YYYY*") Then
        Debug.Print "Match"
   End If
End If
```

Although: The like operator uses wildcharacters... so actually you're matching more than just the string `*XXX*YYY*`...

Comment: Thanks Peter. Yes I know that the * are wildcards and that is fine because actually the string XXX and YYY varies slightly

Comment: Thank you Peter, your solution also works pretty well!